# Validate params from API Post in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am currently building an API which is consumed by third party applications.

I want to know the recommended way to validate the attributes that are passed to my app through a JSON request body. Some of these attributes are converted before I assign them to the model.

For instance:

My model has an attribute `incoterms` that can be either `DDU` or `DDP` and this is validated in my model.

However in the POST request the API client sends a `taxes_duties_paid_by` that can be either `Sender` (which is converted to `DDP`) or `Receiver` (converted to `DDU`)

This is the reason why I have to validate the params before it's even converted.

Comment: You can use `before_action` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters or make a DSL method https://gist.github.com/ryanlecompte/1283413

Comment: before_action is a good option, however, I would prefer using strong parameters and create 2 sets of params to be allowed e.g. `sender_params` and `receiver_params` permitting corresponding params and rails will handle/validate the required params for you.